# Styling an anchor tag as a coloured rectangle, padding not functioning as required. ("Display:Block;" has been applied.)

Tags: html, css, anchor, styling

I am creating a sub-navigation to appear at the bottom of the pages of the site I am designing. It is to be a row of 4-5 coloured rectangles that function as simple links.

I am close to getting them exactly as I want.

However the text needs some padding to look correctly formatted, when I try to use padding the background colour doesn't expand with the padding. Also the padding is behaving in some unusual ways.

I am customising a premium wordpress theme but I don't think that the problem is due to any conflicts. I have replicated the 'modules', as I am calling them, in codepen and they seem identical other than the font.

### Here is my html

`<h2 class="module-heading"><a class="colour-module" title="What is Mentoring?" href="#">What is Mentoring?
<span class="module-content"><br />Find out more about what we do</span></a></h2>`

### And here is my css,

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
line-height: 1.3;
margin-bottom: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
}


h2 {
font-size: 25px;
}

a {
transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms, opacity 300ms;
-moz-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms, opacity 300ms;
-o-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms, opacity 300ms;
-webkit-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms, opacity 300ms;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

.colour-module{
display:block;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#3064A8;
width:200px;/*width is usually set to 100% in a column widget*/
height: 150px;
}

.module-heading{
color: #ffffff;
font-family:'Open-sans', sans-serif;
line-height: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px 10px 20px 10px;
}

.module-content{
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}


.colour-module:hover{
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#3FAF3B;
}
```

### and a link to it running in Codepen,

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CrgzI

I just want to be able to adjust the spacing around the text, otherwise everything is working exactly as I wish it to.

I have tried a couple of other methods to achieve what I want but they were worse, this is the closest I have got.

If anyone can suggest a different method to get the results I want than I will happily give that a shot as well.

I thought that it would be simple to have a coloured box with text in that acts as a link!

Thanks for reading all of this!

Comment: Can you give us an idea what is the ideal layout you want to achieve? It is not very clear to say you want to "adjust the spacing around the text". What should it look like? What should be spacing be like? Where should the spacing go — the padding of the link, or the spacing between the title and the subtitle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added padding to every element in this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbKgn), could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and I'll happily edit the demo to accommodate it.

The only real change I made was adding `display: block;` to `.module-content`

Comment: OMG you genius, that is literally perfect!

It did seem like a lack of "display:block;" might be the problem. I didn't think to apply it to the .module-content! It's been a stressful few weeks working on this.

Thank you!

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone :)! Good luck!

Comment: Dammit, I wasn't insane. Something in the theme is affecting the padding. Worked great in codepen but once I got it into wordpress the padding issue kicked off again.

I will try to find a different method to achieve what I want.